# MySQL procedure, female or male based on identification number

Tags: mysql, procedure

I would like to determine based on identification code if a person is a male or female. Identification code is int(11) and first number of that specifies if it is male or female. So for example code beginning with 2, 4, 6 and 8 are females and 1, 3, 5 and 7 are males.
What I have now (parameter is in_ik int(11):

```
BEGIN

DECLARE s VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '';

IF LEFT(in_ik, 1) % 2 = 0 THEN
    SET s = "female";
ELSEIF LEFT(in_ik, 1) % 2 != 0 THEN
    SET s = "Male";
ELSE
    SET s = "Other";
END IF;
SELECT s;

END
```

When I test the procedure, it says everytime that it is female.
[procedure code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4VcW.png)

Comment: And where is `in_ik` defined/passed in/selected

Comment: it is entered when I am executing the procedure.

Comment: So show us ALL the code for this proceedure please

Comment: I added a link with picture

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue and this code works as expected. Can you give examples where it fails.

Comment: for example 38702116024 gives female, should be male.

Comment: it seems to fail when the number is 11 numbers long

Comment: Solved it, I have to use BIGINT not INT :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really surpising that this fails when passed an 11 digit number ,see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html for maximum sizes for integers (btw (11) means max display size is 11 not store as 11 digit integer) I suggest you change in_ik to big int. In fact I get an error when I try to run this code as is..

Answer (score 0):

If you check for pair  (female)  and odd (male )  you could use directly MOD()  (or integer division %)   instead of left 1 (left  is for string not for integer  )

```
BEGIN

DECLARE s VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '';

IF MOD(in_ik, 2)= 0 THEN
    SET s = "female";
ELSE
    SET s = "Other";
END IF;
SELECT s;

END
```